# Question on the explicit solution of Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am just learning about the fundamental and the general solution of the Laplace equation $$\triangle u = 0.$$

The main Theorem seems to be, that with the fundamental solution $$\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{d(d-2)m^d(B_1(0))}\frac{1}{|x|^{d-2}}$$
(at least for $d\geq 3$) and $f\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we have that
$$u=\Phi\ast f,$$ the convolution of $\Phi$ and $f$ is a solution of $$-\triangle u = f.$$

However, convolution and differentiation commute, so it seems like we should (at least for sufficiently regular $f$) have
$$-\triangle u = -\triangle (\Phi\ast f) = -(\triangle\Phi)\ast f = -0\ast f = 0.$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm confused - you have $B_1(0)$ in the denominator. $B_1(0)$ is a set, the unit ball centered at zero. Did you mean its volume?

Comment: $\Phi$ being a fundamental solution means $\Delta\Phi=\delta$, not $\Delta\Phi=0$.

Comment: @K.defaoite i have $m^d(B_1(0))$ in the denominator. This was indeed meant to refer to the volume. Maybe i should have made this explicit.

Comment: @user10354138 I see. I missed this, indeed. This clears the confusion. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Takirion Ah, right. Thanks for the clarification. I am more used to using $\mu$ to denote measure